Customized error in REST - response entity's body is null even though error was thrown
I have the following REST endpoint:
@PostMapping(path = "/dispatchJob")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> dispatchJob(@RequestBody(required = false) JobDispatchRequestBody dispatchRequestBody) throws FailedToAcceptJobException {

        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());
        Job j = modelMapper.map(dispatchRequestBody.getDispatchRequestsDTO(), Job.class);
        jobsSvc.assignJob(j, dispatchRequestBody.getDispatchEpoch());
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

The "jobsSvc.assignJob" function throws exception:
    @Override
    public synchronized void assignJob(Job j, Long dispatchEpoch) throws FailedToAcceptJobException {
        initJobObject(j);

        throw new FailedToAcceptJobException(new DispatchJobErrorResponse("System is shutting down, not accepting new job!",
                DispatchJobErrorResponse.JobRejectionErrorCode.SystemISShuttingDown));
}

And the exception class is as follows:
@Data
public class FailedToAcceptJobException extends Exception {

    private final DispatchJobErrorResponse dispatchJobErrorResponse;

    public FailedToAcceptJobException(DispatchJobErrorResponse dispatchJobErrorResponse) {
        super("Failed to assign job on agent exception: " + dispatchJobErrorResponse.getMessage());
        this.dispatchJobErrorResponse = dispatchJobErrorResponse;
    }

I created the following handler that is being called once exception is thrown within this endpoint (I validated that through test):
@ExceptionHandler(value = FailedToAcceptJobException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleCustomException(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                         FailedToAcceptJobException ex)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getDispatchJobErrorResponse(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

My issue is, when I'm trying to call this endpoint via post request, I don't get the body and I can't access the error object (this is a test).
String url = "/dispatchJob";
JobDispatchDTO jobDispatchDTO = new JobDispatchDTO();
JobDispatchRequestBody dispatchRequestBody = new JobDispatchRequestBody(jobDispatchDTO,1L);
ResponseEntity<Void> res = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, dispatchRequestBody,Void.class);

I've been playing with it for hours, I realize that eventually I'll have to use object mapper in order to access "DispatchJobErrorResponse" fields, but the body remains null in the response entity no matter what I do.
Please assist

Try using String.class as the response type instead of Void.class. This allows you to receive the raw response body, even if it's an error.

You're thinking about this incorrectly. Your call to postForEntity will throw a HttpStatusCodeException because any 4xx response will cause RestTemplate to throw an exception so there will be no body to deserialize into a ResponseEntity.
To illustrate this, surround your call with a try/catch
try {
  ResponseEntity<Void> res = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, dispatchRequestBody, Void.class);
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
  String error = e.getMessage(); // should contain "400: Failed to assign job on agent exception: System is shutting down, not accepting new job!"
}

If you want to always return a consistent object that may contain errors, create a wrapper class for your domain that will encapsulate both your data and your errors.  In your exception handler, always return a 200 with an instance of this wrapper.
The wrapper would look something like this:
@Data
public class ResponseWrapper <T> {
    T data;
    String errors;
    boolean hasErrors;
}

You would modify your API to return a ResponseEntity of ResponseWrapper, like this:
public ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper<Void>> dispatchJob...

Then modify your error handler to return the ResponseWrapper, with a status of ok.
@ExceptionHandler(value = FailedToAcceptJobException.class)
public ResponseWrapper<?> handleCustomException(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                     FailedToAcceptJobException ex)
{
    ResponseWrapper<?> body = new ResponseWrapper<>();
    body.setErrors(ex.getDispatchJobErrorResponse());
    body.setHasErrors(true);
    return ResponseEntity.ok.body(body);
}

On the calling side, it would look like this:
ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseWrapper<Void>> responseWrapperParameterizedTypeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};
RequestEntity<Void> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(POST, new URI("url"));
ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper<Void>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod POST, dispatchRequestBody, responseWrapperParameterizedTypeReference);

// Now you can do what I believe you want:
if (response.getBody().hasErrors()) {

    response.getBody().getErrors(); // should contain your errors
} else {
    response.getBody().getData(); // would have the data that you set in your controller, if this wasn't a Void return type
}

On a simpler note, if you want to handle the errors from RestTemplate in a more concise manner, consider creating a Component that implements ResponseErrorHandler or extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler.  See this.  A simple implementation would look something like this
import com.phistonemetals.api.exception.RestTemplateException;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.util.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

@Component
public class RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        return response.getStatusCode().is5xxServerError() ||
                response.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        throw new RestTemplateException(IOUtils.toString(response.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}


NOTE!  I do not recommend the approach of creating a wrapper, it defeats the purpose of REST which uses http status codes to indicate status back to the callers.

Thank you for your response, I did hope for an error to be thrown when surrounded it by try/catch, but nothing was thrown. That's what led me to actually look for the body instead, because I'm creating a response entity in the exception handler.

Apparently the issue was the usage of testRestTemplate, that for some reason being injected with handling errors by default. I used regular RestTemplate and indeed got the exception with the expected object
